# angular5 unit testing jasmine+karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a simple method that i want to test:

ts file:

```
policyOptions(event): void {
    this.selectedPolicy = event.srcElement["value"];
    this.detectFormValueChanges();
  }
```

spec file, what i wrote:

```
it("policyOptions function test case", () => {
    const mockSelectedPolicy = {"value": "DEFAULT"};
    component.policyOptions(mockSelectedPolicy);
    component.detectFormValueChanges();
  });
```

html code:

```
    <input id="enable" (change)="policyOptions($event)" type="radio" value="ENABLED" name="antiPhishingSelectPolicy" class="radio__input" [checked]="selectedPolicy==='ENABLED'">
```

I am getting error: `"value is undefined"`. What am i doing wrong? how can i resolve it?

I am new to angular, so i am finding unit testing difficult to overcome. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the dummy data format was incorrect. Here is the test case:

```
it("policyOptions method test case, when DEFAULT is the value", () => {
    const testevent = {
      srcElement: {
        value: "DEFAULT",
      },
    };
    component.policyOptions(testevent);
    expect(component.selectedPolicy).toEqual("DEFAULT");
    component.policyOptions(testevent);
  });
```